# Dell Inspiron 1764 will not start

Tags: laptop, motherboard, webcam, post

Lappy's screen was flickering and the webcam was working only intermittently. There was a lot of ping pong sounds which I narrowed down to device disconnect events, presumably the screen or webcam. So I opened him up and discovered that I could induce the flickering by wiggling the screen cable around. I'm fairly sure the problem was in the cable and not the connector to the motherboard because the flickering occurred if I wiggled the cable while holding the connector still. So bought a new screen cable and fitted it.

Now Lappy will not boot up at all. I think you hardware guys call this no POST. With the battery pack out, the rightmost light (battery) comes on for a second when the power cord is inserted. Then if I press the power button the left most light (power) comes on for 3 seconds. If I press it again I don't get the light again. Curious. The machine makes no sounds at all. I've tried putting the old cable back in but it makes no difference.

Any ideas?

My theories:

- A magnet I've used to fish a screw out has upset something, maybe the hibernation switch
- I've shorted something. I've been testing my "work" with the power button panel loose and resting on the keyboard

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you're not getting any visual or acoustic feedback probably means that the problem is with some **very** crucial part of the system like motherboard, CPU, or their power supply path. I don't think even CMOS memory loss/corruption can be the case.
I suggest doing a thorough disconnection/reconnection and cleaning of the motherboard, connection points, and ... if you know your way around well enough. I've seen truly strange-looking problems getting solved this way.
You can refer to [Dell 1764's Service Manual](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_laptop/esuprt_inspiron_laptop/inspiron-1764_service%20manual_en-us.pdf) if you're unsure of anything.

Comment: Thanks. You've confirmed what I thought. Any idea how I could have fried a component?

Comment: +1 for the service manual link and the never-give-up attempt :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the ping pong sounds was not the screen, it was the webcam - it has a small connector that comes loose on some Inspirons (and older XPS's for that matter). Sometimes (not in your case) all it takes to "fix" it is to press firmly against the screen frame, one inch to the left or to the right of the webcam. This may reseat the connector (or pry it loose once and for all: dead webcam). For the "true" fix you need to carefully pry open the forward-facing screen frame in order to expose the webcam connector, and reseat it firmly with tweezers or needle-nosed pliers. A drop of Superglue will fix the connector forever **and void the warranty**, so you have to weigh your options.

The other symptoms you now have does seem like a short circuit and some component blown. But before buying the explanation (and a new laptop), you can try some manoeuvers:

- verify that it boots neither on battery (even on a charged battery) nor on AC power.
- with AC power and no battery, press and hold the power button for 30 seconds. It used to work on old Inspirons (medium-fresh ones like the 1730 require [Fn key plus power](http://delltags.awardspace.com/dell_diag.html)). On [some models](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~deke/laptopsupport/manuals/d600/diag.htm) you need the *mute* button plus Power.
- if nothing happens, and hoping it's somehow the CMOS that got fritzed - maybe by that loose screw, who knows - try pulling out the CMOS battery to thoroughly zero them and force a new setup.

Apart from that, I'm afraid there's little one can do.

## Update

Okay, I've been thinking over the various symptoms. Mohammad's hypothesis would be good, *except* that the laptop isn't stone cold dead; you **do** get a visual feedback:

> Then if I press the power button the left most light (power) comes on
>   for 3 seconds. If I press it again I don't get the light again

The above *could* be caused by a configuration mismatch (and that's the CMOS). But there is maybe a simpler possibility: *that you have partially displaced the power button panel connector* when you removed the video cable.

- remove the power button panel
- open the power connector latch
- re-seat the connector
- close the latch again and reseat the panel.

Possibly, another connector that could be involved is the mainboard one which is near the display cable connector. Actually, were the problem there, my guess is that you should end up with a dead (albeit easily brought back to life) laptop. Just in case, check those two connectors as well.

(I'm not shooting down Mohammad's suggestion - actually I'm upvoting it - but it is a bit of a voodoo ritual. Mind you, I *have* performed such rituals myself, and they sometimes *do* work indeed. I just keep them last :-) ).

Comment: Thanks. Lappy was well out warranty. I'll try your suggestions.